# How do I use Latex and Rmarkdown to assign parameters from R?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Down below, I have a Tex file that currently has placeholders for where I want to assign parameters from Rmarkdown to produce a pdf.
[image]

If you imagine everything with "%Param" will be something different. What is the correct formatting to set this up to assign the variables in R?

$Param Five% = "Workers'  Compensation- 26 Years of Fund Mmembership"

In my Rmarkdown, I currently have the YAML set up as

```
---
title: "Example"
author: "N N"
date: \today

output:
    pdf_document:
        template: test.tex
---
```

I have not really messed with this portion yet because I am still assembling the template.tex. But I am prepping for the next step.

Thanks

Comment: It's possible that the `brew` package is better suited to this task ... ? https://rdrr.io/rforge/brew/

Comment: I think you would delimit parameters in the template with `$`, not `%`. I would suggest reading through the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-template.html). There are links to examples of templates. You could also consider [Sweave](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552056-Using-Sweave-and-knitr), which has [`\Sexpr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declaring parameters. What is the correct way to declare parameters that will be iterated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70715292/declaring-parameters-what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-parameters-that-will-be)

Comment: I also asked that question ha